# mysql order by, showing uppercase results first

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql query which fetches `AES_ENCRYPTED` names from the table,
I want the result to show in `alphabetical order`,, but the problem is the result is showing **capital results first**..
I mean like

```
A

B

a

b
```

but I want like

```
A

a

B

b
```

this is my `query`..

```
select 
id as id,
AES_DECRYPT(fname,'$_ENCKEY') as fname1,
AES_DECRYPT(lname,'$_ENCKEY') as lname 
from patient 
order by fname1 ASC
```

I also have tried `LOWER, UPPER, UCASE etc....` but no luck...

And I am using **PDO**...

Comment: Maybe it's just a writing mistake, but for me, `A a B a` is not an alphabetical order. You wanted to write `A a B b` instead?

Comment: @Gwenc37 yeah sorry.. it was writing mistake.. I edited the question., thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the return value of AES_ENCRYPT to CHAR.

```
   select 
   id as id,
   CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'$_ENCKEY') AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1 ) as fname1,
   AES_DECRYPT(lname,'$_ENCKEY') as lname 
   from patient 
   order by fname1 collate latin1_general_cs
```

Comment: `Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'`

Comment: since you are using latin1_general_ci collation your character set is not able to use utf8_general_ci collation . Please check the answer now.

Comment: `COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'`.. :( :(

Comment: You are getting the result as utf8 character set . So this collation should work.

Comment: I dont know what problem it has.. but no any answer is helping me out.. :(

Comment: I have updated it . Hope it will work. Worked for me.

Comment: yeah..  that worked.. thank you so much.. I really appreciate your effort... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a case sensitive problem :

Try :

```
select 
id as id,
AES_DECRYPT(fname,'$_ENCKEY') as fname1,
AES_DECRYPT(lname,'$_ENCKEY') as lname 
from patient 
order by fname1 COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' ASC
```

Comment: the link which you posted in the answer is for `sqlite`... and I am having problem in `mysql`...

Comment: @NishantSolanki You are right. I edited my post. try `order by LOWER(fname1) ASC`

Comment: It could come from an encoding problem. What is your dataBase encoding?

Comment: Your table is also latin1_swedish_ci?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50677/discussion-between-gwenc37-and-nishant-solanki)

Comment: Try ORDER BY fname1 COLLATE ‘latin1_general_ci’

Comment: @SQLDBA.. got this error ::  `COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'`